# pfSense on failover won't route with GW on a completely different subnet

Tags: routing, vmware-esx, pfsense

I'm trying to install a `pfSense` with an IP failover (requirement from `online.net`) but I can't get the server to route the requests.

Last time I got it working with the following commands:

```
route add -inet 62.210.137.1/32 -link -iface em0  
route add default 62.210.137.1
```

then download `ShellCmd` and add these commands (for `pfsense` reboot)

But it doesnt work now.

**Useful informations :**

```
ESX IP : 62.210.137.146  
ESX gateway : 62.210.137.1  
IP Failover 212.83.187.120


WAN interface (em0)  
Status up  
MAC address 00:50:56:00:2d:d9  
IPv4 address 212.83.187.120  
Subnet mask IPv4 255.255.255.255  
Gateway IPv4 WANGW 62.210.137.1  
IPv6 Link Local fe80::250:56ff:fe00:2dd9%em0  
ISP DNS servers 127.0.0.1  
Media 1000baseT <full-duplex>  
In/out packets 0/3300 (0 bytes/258 KB)  
In/out packets (pass) 0/3300 (0 bytes/258 KB)  
In/out packets (block) 0/0 (0 bytes/0 bytes)  
In/out errors 0/0  
Collisions 0  

LAN interface (em1)  
Status up  
MAC address 00:0c:29:bd:28:8c  
IPv4 address 10.0.0.1  
Subnet mask IPv4 255.255.255.0  
IPv6 Link Local fe80::20c:29ff:febd:288c%em1  
Media 1000baseT <full-duplex>  
In/out packets 2140/2505 (189 KB/968 KB)  
In/out packets (pass) 2140/2505 (189 KB/968 KB)  
In/out packets (block) 0/0 (0 bytes/0 bytes)  
In/out errors 0/0  
Collisions 0
```

**ping 8.8.8.8 (Main DNS Google)**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.  
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable  
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable  
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

`Ping 212.83.187.120` works

Thanks in advance for you replies and if you find the solution please explain why, this will be easier to understand next time.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add WAN default gateway in order to get internet on the router and clients.

- add gateway as your main WAN IP address - do backup of your pfsense.
- edit backup file - find gateway record and change to correct one for ip failover. save.
- do restore with that file.
- reboot the router.
- make sure you have installed shellcmd and added your strings.

  ```
  route add -inet 62.210.137.1/32 -link -iface em0  
  route add default 62.210.137.1
  ```